# Why is the Chi Square Expected vs Observed in two different structures?

Tags: r

I am sure this is an easy question.  Consider the following code

```
  M <- as.table(rbind(c(762, 327.2, 468), c(484, 239, 477)))
   dimnames(M) <- list(gender = c("F", "M"),
                  party = c("Democrat","Independent", "Republican"))
   (Xsq <- chisq.test(M))  # Prints test summary
   testO<-Xsq$observed   # observed counts (same as M)
   testE<-Xsq$expected   # expected counts under the null
```

if you look at testO it is a table.  testE is a matrix.  Why the heck would these be two different structures for data in identical formats?  Now if you need to join them together you need to convert the observed to a matrix - which isn't obvious.

Comment: Don't know if there is an answer for this. But chisq.test just returns your data unaltered in chisq.test(..)$observed. So if you do, class(chisq.test(as.table(M))$observed), you get a table

Comment: The `chisq.test` expected "a numeric vector or matrix". And tables are matrices but with an extra class: `is.matrix(M)==TRUE`. So since M basically is a matrix, it doesn't change the input (that's just passed through as observed), but since it does all the calculations in "matrix space", it calculates the expected values as a matrix. But the only difference really is that `testO` has an extra class attribute. Otherwise the structure is the same matrix structure underneath. How exactly did you try to join them together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the list that `chisq.test` returns, `Xsq`, also contains `residuals` and `stdres` objects and these are also `tables`. Only `expected` is not a table. But I don't have any problem using `rbind` or `cbind` to combine them. We can even make an array as follows:

```
Results <- array(cbind(Xsq$observed, Xsq$expected), dim=c(2, 3, 2), 
     dimnames=list(gender=c("F", "M"), party=c("Democrat", "Independent",
     "Republican"), c("Observed", "Expected")))
options(digits=5)
ftable(Results, row.vars=1, col.vars=2:3)
#        party Democrat          Independent          Republican         
#              Observed Expected    Observed Expected   Observed Expected
# gender                                                                 
# F              762.00   703.71      327.20   319.78     468.00   533.71
# M              484.00   542.29      239.00   246.42     477.00   411.29
ftable(Results, row.vars=1:2, col.vars=3)
#                     Observed Expected
# gender party                         
# F      Democrat       762.00   703.71
#        Independent    327.20   319.78
#        Republican     468.00   533.71
# M      Democrat       484.00   542.29
#        Independent    239.00   246.42
#        Republican     477.00   411.29
```