# Merging multiple chi square tables into one big table

Tags: r, merge, chi-squared

This is a follow-up question inspired by [dcarlson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1580645/dcarlson)'s answer to the question "[Why is the Chi Square Expected vs Observed in two different structures?](https://question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60341214/why-is-the-chi-square-expected-vs-observed-in-two-different-structures)"

I have 3x flat tables (NN & BB & FF) showing Chi-Square results (Observed & Expected frequencies).

```
NN <- as.table(rbind(c(11, 25), c(32, 27)))
dimnames(NN) <- list(gender = c("Top", "Other"),
                    source = c("You","Partner"))
(Xsq_NN <- chisq.test(NN))

NN_Results <- array(cbind(Xsq_NN$observed, Xsq_NN$expected), dim=c(2, 2, 2), 
                   dimnames=list(Rank = c("Top", "Other"),
                                 Source = c("You", "Partner"), 
                                 c("Observed", "Expected")))
options(digits=3)
ftable(NN_Results, row.vars=1, col.vars=2:3)

BB <- as.table(rbind(c(11, 29), c(32, 23)))
dimnames(BB) <- list(gender = c("Top", "Other"),
                     source = c("You","Partner"))
(Xsq_BB <- chisq.test(BB))

BB_Results <- array(cbind(Xsq_BB$observed, Xsq_BB$expected), dim=c(2, 2, 2), 
                   dimnames=list(Rank = c("Top", "Other"),
                                 Source = c("You", "Partner"), 
                                 c("Observed", "Expected")))
options(digits=3)
ftable(BB_Results, row.vars=1, col.vars=2:3)

FF <- as.table(rbind(c(6, 5), c(37, 47)))
dimnames(FF) <- list(gender = c("Top", "Other"),
                     source = c("You","Partner"))
(Xsq_FF <- chisq.test(FF))

FF_Results <- array(cbind(Xsq_FF$observed, Xsq_FF$expected), dim=c(2, 2, 2), 
                   dimnames=list(Rank = c("Top", "Other"),
                                 Source = c("You", "Partner"), 
                                 c("Observed", "Expected")))
options(digits=3)
ftable(FF_Results, row.vars=1, col.vars=2:3)
```

I am greatly struggling to now merge the three tables, however keeping and adding headers to the columns.

This is the attempt:

```
# Name contingency tables
NN_table <- ftable(NN_Results, row.vars = 1, col.vars = 2:3)
BB_table <- ftable(BB_Results, row.vars = 1, col.vars = 2:3)
FF_table <- ftable(FF_Results, row.vars = 1, col.vars = 2:3)

# Combine the tables horizontally
Merged_Table <- cbind(NN_table, BB_table, FF_table)

# Print the merged table
print(Merged_Table)

> Merged_Table
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
[1,]   11 16.3   25 19.7   11 18.1   29 21.9    6  4.98     5  6.02
[2,]   32 26.7   27 32.3   32 24.9   23 30.1   37 38.02    47 45.98
```

My problem is that I now have all the headers lost... I would like to have column headers to hopefully look like this:
[image: Goal Layout]

Finally, I would like to add the chi-square (p-value) below per item/column:
[image]

Thankful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually make this kind of table using the `flextable` package

```r
# Combine the tables horizontally
Merged_Table <- cbind(NN_table, BB_table, FF_table)

# From your Merged_Table we add the p.values and colnames
Merged_p <-
  as.data.frame(rbind(round(Merged_Table,2),
                      rep(
                        paste0(
                          round(c(Xsq_NN$statistic, Xsq_BB$statistic, Xsq_FF$statistic),2), " (",
                          round(c(Xsq_NN$p.value, Xsq_BB$p.value, Xsq_FF$p.value),3), ")"
                        )
                        , each = 4)))

# Making the table names
colnames(Merged_p) <- paste( 
   rep(c("NN", "BB", "FF"), each = 4 ),
   rep(c("You","You","Partner","Partner"), 3),
   rep(c("Observed","Expected"), 6), sep = "_" )

Merged_p <- cbind(" " = c("Top","Other","Chi-2 (p-value)"), Merged_p)

library(flextable)

your_table <- 
flextable(Merged_p) |>
  ftExtra::span_header() |>
  theme_booktabs()|>
  merge_h() |> 
  hline(i = c(1,2,3),part = 'header') |>
  vline(j = seq(1,13, by = 2)) |>
  align(align = 'center', part = 'all')

# Print the merged table with p-values
# print(your_table)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! 
Can we limit the digits to 1 behind the comma?
Is it easy to add the chi-square value before the p-value (e.g. "chi-2 (p-value)" per cell )?

"Merged_Table" has the correct format with decimals, then "Merged_p" shows more decimal places, probably because of the added p-values?

Comment: Sure. You need to use round when creating the `Merged_p` table. I have edited my answer.